# SUMIF and COUNTIF for SQL

Tags: sql

I have some data that looks like this:

```
col1, col2, col3
A,    1.2,  A|X|Y|Z
B,    0.3,  B|X|Y|Z
X,    1.0,  X|Y|Z
Y,    0.2,  Y|Z
Z,    1.0,  Z
```

I want to select the rows where the item in col1 appears in the col3 pipe-delimited list other than its own list. And for each of those items, I want to count the number of rows where that item appears in col3, and also sum col2 where that condition is met. So the results should be something like this:

```
col1, foo,  bar
X,    2,    1.5
Y,    3,    2.5
Z,    4,    2.7
```

I've been trying to use CASE WHEN and LIKE to do this (see below), but it's not working. For foo I get all zeroes, and for bar I get null. Maybe I need some kind of subquery that I don't understand how to use?

```
SELECT
  col1,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN col3 LIKE col1 THEN 1 END) as foo,
  SUM(CASE WHEN col3 LIKE col1 THEN col2 END) as bar

FROM table

GROUP BY
  col1
```

Comment: (1) Fix your data model.  Storing multiple values in a string is not the SQL way to store data. (2) Tag with the database you are using.  (3) Your results don't seem related to the sample data (`Z` is never in `col1`).

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a self-join.  In standard SQL, it would look like:

```
select t.col1, count(*) as foo, sum(col2) as bar
from t join
     t t2
     on '|' || t2.col3 || '|' like '%|' || t.col1 || '|%'
group by t.col1;
```

The syntax might vary in the database you are actually using, but the idea should work with whatever string concatenation mechanism your database uses.

Answer (score 1):

With a self join and aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.col1, COUNT(*) foo, SUM(t2.col2) bar
FROM tablename t1 INNER JOIN tablename t2
ON t2.col1 <> t1.col1 AND CONCAT('|', t2.col3, '|') LIKE CONCAT('%|', t1.col1, '|%')
GROUP BY t1.col1
```

The above code will work in MySql.
For other databases you can use their concatenation operators like `||` or `+`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f18d9f915fa868d58cf27430484f6e96).
Results:

```
> col1 | foo | bar
> :--- | --: | --:
> X    |   2 | 1.5
> Y    |   3 | 2.5
> Z    |   4 | 2.7
```